# Are factor loadings regression weights or correlations? (orthogonal rotatet EFA)

Tags: factor-analysis

Are "factor loadings" (orthogonal rotated) in exploratory factor analysis (EFA)
[correlations](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0095798418771807) or [standardized regression weights](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/nursing-and-health-professions/exploratory-factor-analysis#:%7E:text=EFA%20is%20executed%20on%20the,loadings%20are%20standardized%20regression%20weights.)?

For instance in r, the factor loadings are very high, if the correlations of the variables are strong (but not exact the same as the bivariate correlations), and the standardized regression weights are very small.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(id = 1:200) |> 
mutate(z1 = rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = 1),
      z2 = rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = 1)) |> 
mutate(v1_1 = z1 + rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = .1), 
      v2_1 = z1 + rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = .1),
      v3_1 = z1 + rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = .1), 
      v1_2 = z2 + rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = .1),
      v2_2 = z2 + rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = .1), 
      v3_2 = z2 + rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = .1)) |> 
 select(-c(z1, z2))

fa <- factanal(data, factors = 2, scores = "regression", rotation = "varimax")

fa

data_fa <- cbind(data, fa$scores)

cor(data_fa) 

fit <- lm(Factor1 ~ v1_1 + v2_1 + v3_1 + v1_2 + v2_2 + v3_2, data = data_fa)

summary(fit)
```

```
Loadings:
     Factor1 Factor2
id                  
v1_1  0.993         
v2_1  0.995         
v3_1  0.996         
v1_2          0.994 
v2_2          0.994 
v3_2          0.992 

correlations:
             Factor1       Factor2
id      0.0568848249  0.0071987895
v1_1    0.9948765006 -0.0044600395
v2_1    0.9968916461  0.0119593283
v3_1    0.9975826189  0.0054520197
v1_2    0.0628987259  0.9952432981
v2_2    0.0607294808  0.9958072362
v3_2    0.0569253903  0.9936277082
Factor1 1.0000000000  0.0002178429
Factor2 0.0002178429  1.0000000000


standardized regression weights:
lm(formula = Factor1 ~ v1_1 + v2_1 + v3_1 + v1_2 + v2_2 + v3_2, 
    data = data_fa)

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -4.286e-02  1.348e-05 -3180.341   <2e-16 ***
v1_1         2.506e-01  1.026e-04  2442.716   <2e-16 ***
v2_1         3.587e-01  1.133e-04  3166.710   <2e-16 ***
v3_1         4.233e-01  1.194e-04  3544.716   <2e-16 ***
v1_2        -1.085e-03  1.085e-04    -9.992   <2e-16 ***
v2_2        -1.888e-03  1.140e-04   -16.560   <2e-16 ***
v3_2        -1.977e-03  9.964e-05   -19.845   <2e-16 ***
```

Comment: I don't think it helps to mix factor analysis terminology with principal component (PC) analysis  terminology.  Also, in practice you may need to specify what software you're using. Some comments I've seen on this site only make sense if people are either very confused or using quite different software from me with different definitions. In given software, a simple test is whether the correlation between a PC and a variable is identical to a loading,  In Stata, it is emphatically not the same; a loading is more like a regression coefficient.

Comment: I am currently more focused on "Exploratory Factor Analysis". Andy Field's says (whether related to SPSS or R): "$Factor = b_1 Variable_{1i} + b_2 Variable_{2i} + ... + e_i,$" and "The b's in the equation represent the factor loadings." Bortz defines factor loadings as bivariate correlation: "$r_{ij} = 1/n*\sum_{m=1}^n(f_{mj}*z_{mi})$. This definition is from pure statistical theory and not specific to any software. The bivariate correlations are only identical to the BETAS when the variables are uncorrelated, which would be nonsensical for an Exploratory Factor Analysis (EFA).

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but Andy Field is usually mentioned on CV only as a source of confused and confusing explanations. Otherwise there is no error term in PCA. If your question is really about factor analysis, then please remove all mention of PCs.

Comment: I don’t practise FA and can’t advise further on it. Sorry.